# How to explicity fail e2e tests on unexpected behavior?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, protractor, nodejs

I am currently using protractor but the idea would be similar for any flavor of Selenium. Right now, depending on which step the test is on, my current framework will wait for elements to be interactable before proceeding. What I would rather do is explicitly fail if the test encounters some unexpected behavior.

For example, let's say I am filling out a form and expected behavior is that when the form is submitted I am redirected to another page in the app. Typically, I will wait for the next element I want to interact with to be enabled in such a way for me to do that. Now, assume something went wrong with the form and instead of proceeding I get an error (i.e. red toast) and the form doesn't get submitted or the page doesn't redirect. The problem I've noticed in this scenario is that the test will wait for the element, hit the default timeout and throw an error, then it will attempt the next step in the test, hit the timeout and error, and so on. Instead of doing all this waiting I would rather explicitly fail and move on to the next test.

I'm looking for ideas on how to explicitly fail in this scenario and how to make the mechanism for failing reusable so it's not scattered all over my framework. Anyone done anything similar to this that worked well?

I've used `protractor-fail-fast` before but I don't want to use that in this situation. That package will abort the entire test run on the first error/failure. In this case, I want the full suite of tests to run, I just want a specific test to immediately fail and move on to the next test when it encounters some unexpected behavior in my app. I know I will need a custom solution but I'm having trouble thinking through what that solution would looklike. Looking for ideas...

Comment: I can't answer the question, as I don't know anything about Protractor tests yet.  I'm familiar with other automated testing though, and can say Protractor should automatically be failing the current test case and moving on to the next on any fail/error.  There's been a bug open for this for 2 years: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3234  Last update suggests if you're on the latest Protractor maybe it just works correctly now.  Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm, yeah not quite what I'm looking for. It's working fine if an assertion fails. That's completely different. I'm talking about a situation where you need to complete a certain number of steps in the test case before you get to the assertion and one of the steps has failed. Making it impossible to complete any of the additional steps before the assertion. I want to fail the test on the first step that fails and move on instead of waiting for all the steps to run their course and then fail on the assertion.

Comment: I guess a better way to describe it is that if I use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()` or `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()` the test will not fail if these functions timeout before the element is visible in the DOM or becomes clickable. It just throws a timeout error and moves on the the next step. Looking for some ideas on how to explicitly fail if something like that happens that could be reused for multiple scenarios. Maybe I'm overthinking it. I don't know. Just having a hard time picturing how this would work.

Comment: +1Excellent question.

Comment: Why would a next test start if the first one throws a `TimeoutException`? If something like this is thrown, the test fails and results in an `error`. Unless the second test is dependent on the first one, it should not matter, if it is then this is what should be fixed as making test dependent on each other is bad practice.

Comment: @Moro My problem is not with the test itself it is with a test step. If a step fails due to a timeout, then the next step will execute and again wait for the default timeout interval before failing. Instead of executing subsequent steps, I want to immediately fail on the first timeout and move on. To put it simply, Lets say my test has 5 steps. If step two times out for some reason, element not present/interactable, etc., then steps 3-5 will also attempt to execute and wait for the full timeout interval before failing. There is a lot of unnecessary waiting happening in this scenario.

Comment: In `Java` tests are run via `junit`. I ve seen `junit` implementation for `js`. This one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit mentions the flags you need (fail on unhandled) etc. Maybe use it as a test runner?

Answer (score 1):

#### Implement exception handling.

The solution in these scenarios which worked for me is, **checking for console errors on each form submissions( post requests)** and raising the JavaScript error which needs to caught on global framework level so that solution is not scattered all over the framework and raised from individual 'it' blocks and caught on global framework level code which will be executed on after each 'it' block completion.

This global code on detecting an (raised ) JavaScript error will immediately fail& terminate the current test and move on to the next test in the suite for the execution.

> The key is to understand the AUT's internal structure and setup the
> hooks at the right places.